# Pandas datareader errors

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo, datareader

I have been successfully using a script like this for months using google as the data provider.  A few days ago it stopped working.  Here is the input:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as wb
from datetime import date, datetime, time, timedelta
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay

data_provider = 'google' # 'google', 'quandl', or 'yahoo'

today = date.today()
four_days_ago = today - BDay (4)

tickers = [{'ACET':1},{'HBAN':2},{'HPQ':3},{'IPG':4},{'AOSL':5},{'HBI':6},{'NRG':7},{'IBM':8},{'MMM':9}]

enter_list = []
rank_list = []

for x in tickers:
    for ticker, rank in x.items():
        try:
            df = wb.DataReader (ticker, data_provider, four_days_ago, today)
            print ('reading data for ' + ticker + ' from ' + data_provider)
        except:
            print ('\ncan not read data for ' + ticker + ' from ' + data_provider)

        if df.iloc[1]['Low'] < df.iloc[0]['Low']:
            enter_list.append (ticker)
            rank_list.append (rank)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ticker' : enter_list, 'rank' : rank_list}, columns = ['ticker', 'rank'])

if len(df2) == 0:
    print ('\nthere are no qualifying stocks')
else:
    print ('\nlower stocks\n')
    print (df2)
```

Here is the output:

```
reading data for ACET from google
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dvdad\Anaconda3.4.2.0.64.bit\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2483, in get_value
return libts.get_value_box(s, key)
  File "pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx", line 923, in pandas._libs.tslib.get_value_box (pandas\_libs\tslib.c:18843)
  File "pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx", line 932, in pandas._libs.tslib.get_value_box (pandas\_libs\tslib.c:18477)
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\stocks\question 8 for stack overflow.py", line 25, in <module>
if df.iloc[1]['Low'] < df.iloc[0]['Low']:
  File "C:\Users\dvdad\Anaconda3.4.2.0.64.bit\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 601, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "C:\Users\dvdad\Anaconda3.4.2.0.64.bit\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2491, in get_value
raise e1
  File "C:\Users\dvdad\Anaconda3.4.2.0.64.bit\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2477, in get_value
tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 98, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas\_libs\index.c:4404)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 106, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas\_libs\index.c:4087)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 154, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\_libs\index.c:5126)
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1210, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\_libs\hashtable.c:20523)
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1218, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\_libs\hashtable.c:20477)
KeyError: 'Low'
```

Here is the output when the data provider is quandl:

```
reading data for ACET from quandl
reading data for HBAN from quandl
reading data for HPQ from quandl
reading data for IPG from quandl
reading data for AOSL from quandl

can not read data for HBI from quandl
reading data for NRG from quandl
reading data for IBM from quandl
reading data for MMM from quandl

lower stocks

  ticker  rank
0   HBAN     2
1    IPG     4
2    IBM     8
3    MMM     9
```

Here is the output when the data reader is yahoo:

```
reading data for ACET from yahoo
reading data for HBAN from yahoo
reading data for HPQ from yahoo
reading data for IPG from yahoo
reading data for AOSL from yahoo
reading data for HBI from yahoo
reading data for NRG from yahoo

can not read data for IBM from yahoo
reading data for MMM from yahoo

lower stocks

  ticker  rank
0   HBAN     2
1    HPQ     3
2    IPG     4
3   AOSL     5
4    HBI     6
5    NRG     7
6    IBM     8
```

The yahoo output changes when it is run.  Here is some later output:

```
reading data for ACET from yahoo
reading data for HBAN from yahoo
reading data for HPQ from yahoo
reading data for IPG from yahoo
reading data for AOSL from yahoo
reading data for HBI from yahoo
reading data for NRG from yahoo
reading data for IBM from yahoo
reading data for MMM from yahoo

lower stocks

  ticker  rank
0   HBAN     2
1    HPQ     3
2    IPG     4
3   AOSL     5
4    HBI     6
5    NRG     7
```

Does anyone know what is happening here?
Is the problem due to creating multiple dataframes with a loop?
Is the problem pinging the server too much / too quickly?

Thanks in advance,
David